# opengl cannot find libraries in mingw compiler netbeans

Tags: c++, opengl, netbeans, cygwin, mingw

```
cd 'C:\Users\Deepa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\game' C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug "/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Deepa/Documents/NetBeansProjects/game' "/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/game.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Deepa/Documents/NetBeansProjects/game'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
g++    -c -g -s -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/game build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o -lglew32 -lglew32s -lglut32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lglew32s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lglut32
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/game.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Deepa/Documents/NetBeansProjects/game'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Deepa/Documents/NetBeansProjects/game'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 6s)
```

im using a minGW compiler but " /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lglew32s " it seems to be in cygwin.. 
why is it so? and i cant build the file help please

Comment: You need to tell in your `makefile` the directories to search for external, already compiled, libraries.

Comment: Already linked the libraries

Comment: Your error says "cannot find" followed by a wrong filename "-lglew32s". You should review your makefile; it seems you set the libraries in wrong parameter.